# Log4net doesn't create a log file on a production server

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I know there are already a lot of log4net questions asked on Stack Overflow but they can't seem to fix my specific problem.

The log4net configuration below is used for my application.

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="E:\Logs\" />
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd'_APP.log'" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <immediateFlush value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="DATE" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date||%2thread||%-5level||%logger||%message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

I left out some parts that are not interesting. Using this configuration the application is not logging on the production server. On my local development PC it is working fine. When I enable log4net debugging mode I see it can't access the "E:\Logs\" directory because the access is denied.

I added all of the needed permissions to this folder already. Now here comes the part I don't get. After some debugging I found out that appending something after the \ in the  tag, it suddenly works. So the configuration below works fine.

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="E:\Logs\x" />
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd'_APP.log'" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <immediateFlush value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="DATE" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date||%2thread||%-5level||%logger||%message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

This creates a log file x2018-11-07_APP.log, but I don't want to append the x...

Can someone clarify for me why it behaves like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Might be permission for writing file not enabled

Comment: What version of log4net is in use? Answer may depend on this.

Comment: Have you tried: `<file value="E:\Logs\.log" />
    <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd'_APP'" /> <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>` ?

Comment: If it is ok to change to "APP_2018-11-07.log" you could also try `<file value="E:\Logs\APP_.log" /> <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd" /> <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>`

Comment: With a similar issue I was able to fix things using `rollingStyle value="Composite"` (also needs `<staticLogFileName value="false" />`). You can also try to prepend the current datePattern value with two single quotes simulating a starting string, i.e. `"''yyyy-MM-dd'_APP.log'"`

Comment: @Fildor your solution worked, thanks!

Comment: @Filder, log4net version 2.0.8 is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer provided by Fildor worked like a charm.

```
<file value="E:\Logs\.log" /> 
<datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd'_APP'" /> 
<preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
```

It's still weird that it's working fine on the development PC.